# How to require bluetooth enabled in whole application

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to require bluetooth enabled in whole application, but how can I do it?

When I'm using just main activity, the code works great. But when I go to another activity and then disable BT broadcast send me signal to enable BT but after that the "onActivityResult" method is never more called.

How can I write a globaly requiring BT? For all activities (and preferences) in my application.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case Bluetooth.REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                // some stuff here
            }
            else
            {
                // exitapp();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

receiver

```
protected final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED))
            {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                        BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);

                if(state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF)
                {
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE), Bluetooth.REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

and of course

```
startReceiver(mReceiver); // onCreate()
stopReceiver(mReceiver); // onDestroy()
```

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: After I'm going to another activity the receiver is not working again (yeah probably is stopped in onDestroy())? I rlly don't know, maybe I need to put receivers to all activities? Oh god, I hope it's not true.

```
    import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class BluetoothService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (bluetoothReceiver != null) {
            this.unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver);
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public BroadcastReceiver bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED))
            {
                final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
                Intent x = new Intent("btfilter");
                intent.putExtra("state", state);
                sendBroadcast(x);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

MainActivity onCreate

```
    btintent= new Intent(this, BluetoothService.class);
        startService(btintent);
registerReceiver(mServiceUpdatesReceiver, new IntentFilter("btfilter"));
```

MainActivity onDestroy()

```
unregisterReceiver(mServiceUpdatesReceiver);
```

receiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver mServiceUpdatesReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);

        if(state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF)
        {
            // enable request
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). It can work even with the app closed. If you don't know any about it, a quick description: It's a context with no user interface.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question... I'm probably doing something wrong, can you look at that? This works like the previous version haha, no difference.

Comment: Just 1 difference of course, the bt is not requested in another activity.